# How to ssh into B instance from remotely using A instance using python. Localhost > Instance A > Instance B

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I want to ssh remotely to B instance from already ssh into A instance.

What are the other libraries or function in python which support my scenario for using/accessing Instance B using already connected to Instance A via localhost?
If python doesn't support this what are the other ways to accomplish this?

I have tried paramiko library but I was able to connect to only one instance using:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('<PEM_FILE>.pem')
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=ip, username=username, pkey=key)
```

And used this command to execute commands in remote instance as I want to execute `ssh` command under `sudo su`:
`stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo su')`

And now I want to ssh into another instance from this remote instance. So I tried basic ssh command:
`stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ssh -i <PEM_FILE>.pem <username>@<ip>')`

But I wasn't able to ssh into B instance.

I have also tried scenario with this command:
`os.system("ssh -t <PEM_FILE>.pem usernameA@hostA 'ssh -t <PEM_FILE>.pem usernameB@hostB'")`

Expectation: I should be able to run commands in Instance B remotely.

Comment: Yes I want to run the `ssh -i <PEM_FILE>.pem <username>@<ip>` under `sudo su` command. I updated the problem description.

Comment: It is about switching over to different user, rather I want to ssh into another instance.

Comment: What if we ignore the sudo su, How would one be able to run `ssh` command and run some commands on that second remote instance?